# Time oriented design in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, temporal-tables

I've been reading Snodgrass's "Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL" and I'm consulting other documents as well, but I'm willing to find more modern stuff about time-oriented design for databases and the tools available for that in **Postgresql**.

Also found this [document](https://sigmodrecord.org/publications/sigmodRecord/1209/pdfs/07.industry.kulkarni.pdf).

I would be grateful just with any link or advice on the topic discussing:

- Temporal and bitemporal tables
- Coalescing
- Validity, applicability time, transaction time
- Primary keys, constraints and referential integrity in temporal DBs
- Design and good design practices for temporal DBs
- Native Postgresql solutions for all of the above

I have still more to read from the book and I've discovered some SQL:2011 issues about time, but they'are not implemented in Postgresql.

There's still some things I don't know how to handle or understand, for example, I found [this article](https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/7/73/Range-types-pgopen-2012.pdf) mentioning this:

```
CREATE TABLE travel_log (
 id serial PRIMARY KEY,
 name varchar(255),
 travel_range daterange,
 EXCLUDE USING gist (travel_range WITH &&)
);
```

which I understand it could be useful for not having overlapping rows, but even though I searched the Postgresql docs, I only read what the EXCLUDE does and that gist is just some type of INDEX, but I can't figure out which kind of syntax is the "WITH &&" thing and what does it provide.

I would be happy just having resources where I could learn about all this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WITH` keyword defines the operator which is used to test for "equality" between two rows.

A regular unique index is just a special case of an exclusion constraint. If you were to define a "normal" unique constraint using an exclusion constraint, you would use `=` as the operator, e.g: `exclude using btree (id with =)` instead of `unique (id)`

---

The `&&` for range types is the ["overlaps" operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) which tests if two ranges, well, overlap.

e.g.

```
daterange('2019-01-01', '2019-02-21') && daterange('2019-02-08', '2019-03-01')
```

returns true (as the ranges overlap)

while

```
daterange('2019-01-01', '2019-02-21') && daterange('2019-02-22', '2019-03-01')
```

will return false as there is no overlap.