# How to check if a time has been taken by other user?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, php

Let's say I'll add the first user insert into horarios(user, start_time, end_time) values ('7','09:00:00',10:30:00')
With this data on the table the system should only accept for the next value values like ('7','10:31:00', '11:30:00') mean from 9:00am to 11:30am it will not be possible because this user will be unavailable

I found some samples but I got no success.
**Note: please don't worry about SQL injection I'll deal with it later.**

**This is what I got so far**

```
$query = "SELECT start_time, end_time FROM horarios WHERE user='$subcat' 
AND start_time >= '$start_time' AND end_time <= '$end_time';";

$result= pg_query($con, $query);
$rows = pg_num_rows($result);
$query = @pg_query ($con, $sql);
if ($query == NULL){
    echo "the number $subcat is busy";
    exit (0);
}else ($rows===0) {
    $sql = "insert into...;";
    echo $sql;  
}
```

Comment: Why the `mysql` tag?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so that I can get both ideas from postgres and mysql. I have get many ideas from mysql and implement to postgres.

Comment: Sql injection is always a problem, lets say we get here a user, that doesn't know about sl injection and copies your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time oriented design in Postgresql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/230392/time-oriented-design-in-postgresql)

Comment: That code needs to be put in a transaction.

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres I would use:

```
SELECT *
FROM horarios 
  AND (start_time, end_time) overlaps ($start_time, $end_time)
  AND "user" <> 'user_to_check';
```

This checks if there are no overlapping (start_time, end_time) intervals for a *different* user then the one for which you are trying to insert the new row.

---

In fact, in Postgres you don't actually need the check, you could create an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION) that prevents such an entry completely.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I edited my question. Would you please take a look